# Facebook insights api Positive Negative Feedback

Tags: facebook

I am trying to find the fields that represent the Facebook Positive/Negative feedback for Ads within the Insights API. Searching here and cant find it

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/fields/v2.8

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain that data from the `relevance_score` field. It'll give a response like this:

```
"relevance_score": {
    "score": "8",
    "positive_feedback": "HIGH",
    "negative_feedback": "LOW",
    "status": "OK"
}
```